# Existence of non-constant entire function whose image is not all of $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there existing any non-constant entire function whose image is not all of $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$e^z$ is never zero. Its image is $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. To see this, let $z = a+ib$. Then $e^z = e^a e^{ib}$. Observe that $e^a$ takes on every strictly positive real value, and $e^{ib}$ takes on every complex value on the unit circle $|z| = 1$.

This is as pathological as it can get. By the [Little Picard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), the image of a nonconstant entire function is either all of $\mathbb C$ or all of $\mathbb C$ minus one point.